# Mootools: inject vs adopt

Tags: events, mootools, element, inject

I want to dynamically add some preconfigured HTML-Elements in use of a 'click'-event with mootools.

So I can make it work with my basic knowledge, although it isn´t very nifty. I coded this so far...

This is my preconfigured element, with some text, a classname and some event, cause i wanna have events already added, when it´s inserted into my container:

```
        var label = new Element('label', {
            'text': 'Label',
            'class': 'label',
            'events': {
                'click': function(el){
                    alert('click');
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is my function, which adds the label-Element:

```
        function addText(){
            $('fb-buildit').addEvent('click', function(){                   
           row.adopt(label, textinput, deletebtn);
            $('the-form').adopt(row.clone());
            row.empty();

    /*
    label.clone().inject($('the-form'));
    textinput.inject($('the-form'));
    deletebtn.inject($('the-form'));
    */

            });
        }
```

The second part which uses inject also works, but there, my click-Event, which fires the "alert('click')" works too. The method with adopt doesn´t add any event to my label Object, when its inserted in the dom.

Can anyone help me with this. I just wanna know why adobt ignores my "events" settings and inject doesn´t.

Thanks in advance.

(sorry for my english ^^)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you go `label.clone().inject` but `row.adopt(label)` and not `row.adopt(label.clone())` -

either way. .clone() does not [cloneEvents](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event#Element:cloneEvents) for you - you need to do that manually.

```
var myclone = label.clone();
myclone.cloneEvents(label);
row.adopt(label);
```

this is how it will work

as for why that is, events are stored in the Element storage - which is unique per element. mootools assigns a uid to each element, eg, label = 1, label.clone() -> 2, label.clone() -> 3 etc.

this goes to `Storage[1] = { events: ... }` and so forth. cloning an element makes for a new element.uid so events don't work unless you implicitly use `.cloneEvents()`

you are sometimes not doing `.clone()` which works because it takes the ORIGINAL element along with its storage and events.

**suggestion** consider looking into [event delegation](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Element.Delegation). you could do

```
formElement.addEvent("click:relay(label.myLabel)", function(e, el) {
    alert("hi from "+ el.uid);
});
```

this means no matter how many new elements you add, as long as they are of type `label` and class `myLabel` and children of `formElement`, the click will always work as the event bubbles to the parent.